# How to check what service is using a particular configuration file?

Tags: linux, configuration, open-files

I'm new to Linux, and I need to know if there is a way to check which service or program is using a particular configuration file.

A different deployment on the server is failing, and the error message is:

```
file /opt/deployment/dev/deploy.cfg busy
```

This means that the file `deploy.cfg` is busy.

1. How may I tell who or what keeps the file busy.
2. How would I make the file "not busy".

Comment: You can try `man lsof`

Answer (score 0):

Try `lsof` command and see what program is using a particular file, for example:
`lsof /opt/deployment/dev/deploy.cfg`